# how to get observable resolved value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I need to get a service call value within `app.component.ts` file, i need this value before any other view gets loaded because they need this value from redux store and check this within theirs`ngOnInit()` methods.

I've tried using a promise and perform logic within .then() method..., didn't work. I've also tried working with the observable methods

`next: x =>, error: err => and complete: () =>` but the same issue persists: i don't get the expected behavior because when the other views initialize they get an empty value from store because the service hasn't finished returning at that moment.
I found the resolver() functionality, but since `app.component.ts` is not routed as other components i can't use this.

app.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.storeUserReportAccessService.checkUserReportAccess().subscribe((response) => {
  this.store.dispatch(new StoreUserReportAccess(response));
  }
}
```

service:

```
checkUserReportAccess(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.postAPI(AWS_GET_USER_REPORT_ACCESS_URL,
            null).pipe(map(payload => {
            let access = payload.json();
            return access.HasAccess;
        }));
}
```

Comment: provide service code for observable at service side

Comment: Ok, sure. Done.

Comment: How are you initializing the value in your store? Does it have a default value? Is it null or does it default to true/false? If you are initializing the value to false then it should be loading the view for a false value until you get the actual value back from your service at which time the view should update to reflect the change in value.

Comment: You need to provide your selector, your effect and your reducer to get some help. First of all, your app.component.ts should dispatch and action and not wait for the service. An effect should call your service than dispatch a success which would set your data in your reducer and would set your user right. Your other components need to subscribe to a selector which point to your user right in the store.

Comment: @JCherryhomes yes, i'm initializing the value as false, but the view doesn't update the value when the service returns...

Comment: @ukn i don't use selector neither effect, just redux store with actions and reducers. The app.component.ts dispatch the action based on the service response value, so i need the service to return the response before other views get loaded.

Comment: How are you checking the value in your other components if not with a select? Is this using ngrx or some other state management library? If this is ngrx you would usually dispatch an action and your reducer will update the state. Your other components should just need to subscribe to that slice of state using a selector to be notified when that value changes.

Comment: Observable is used for asynchronous task and I think in your case, you are not getting complete data before views intialized. Have you tried `Observable.of`? It will send notification after complete data fetch.